# Understanding Queue for concurrency sakes in Java

Tags: java, collections, queue

I'm reading B. Goetz Java Concurrency In Practice and now I'm at the section about Concurrent Collections. He describes the `Queue` interface added in Java 5.0 as follows:

> While you can simulate the behavior of a `Queue` with a `List` — in fact,
>   `LinkedList` also implements `Queue`—the `Queue` classes were added because
>   eliminating the random-access requirements of List admits more
>   efficient concurrent implementations.

It seems a bit confused. I looked at the [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) interface and noticed that it doesn't implement [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html), but [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does. That's quite obvious as that `LinkedList` provides linear time random access to its elements.

Couldn't you explain what he meant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's not referring to the `RandomAccess` marker interface, but the random access methods such as `get(index)`. When implementing a `Queue` you don't need to worry about implementing those methods, as they could be extremely inefficient and possibly prevent you from making the class as performant as you'd like.